# How to position an element i.e. footer at the the bootom of the page without absolute property?

Tags: html, css

I want to put the footer at the bottom of the page

To position an element i.e. footer at the the bootom of the page without absolute property

Answer (score 0):

use position: fixed instead of position: absolute for the .footer css

Answer (score 0):

Hard to understand your question without seeing any code. But generally this won't be achieved by using position:absolute or fixed.

Fixed won't put it at the end of the page, it would put it at the bottom of the screen.

Please add your code to your question. Usually the Footer is the last div within your body tags.